# Possible to create a multi-user/shared session/instance in Java EE?

Tags: java, session, jakarta-ee

I am attempting to write a Java EE application where multiple clients share the state of an instance of an application, the instance could be something like a document. Think something like Google Docs where multiple users edit the same document.

The approach I'm taking so far is to save the state to the database, using an Entity, with every change by a client. At such a change I then send the new state to the other clients connected (subscribing) to the instance.

My worry with this approach is, what happens when/if the application scales? At the moment any change is registered to the DB even if it is just for a short while, like a quick change that is overridden by another user. Also, information such as which users are connected to the instance and history of changes is stored to the DB. This seems inefficient to me to go back and forth between the DB.

With this my questions are:

- Can I create multiple instances who's individual states are stored in an EJB, or something else?
- Can I have an individual instances live for as long as there are users connected to this instance?
- Can I share the state of an individual instance between multiple connected clients?
- Can I detect when the last user disconnects from an instance so I can save its final state?

The questions might be large but I am mainly interested in, what concepts in Java EE should I be looking into?

Comment: I'm not able to answer fully, but would application scope be of any use here? http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjbbk.html

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your problem matches to a publish / subscribe mecanism like the one into JMS queues ?
https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnceh.html